# Access - User tacking history system

Tags: authentication, ms-access-2010, history

I am designing an Access database and I would like to set up a user history tracking system.

My Objective: **Save all the logins and users actions (login attempts and searches)**

Doing so, I got 1 table and 2 forms:

1. Login form where all the user register *login dialog*
2. Seach criteria form *critera form*
3. History table woith the following fields:  Date, user, Sourcetable, researchhistory, comments *user activity tracker*

Let's focus on the login system first:

**How could I have the action registered as "login success" in comments everytime the login is a success and attempt login in the opposite case?**

For example to have
24/03/15 - User1 - Login Dialog - - Login Success
24/03/15 - User2 - Login Dialog - - Attempt Login
24/03/15 - User1 - Navigation form - - Logoff

Here is what I had coded in the first place:

```
Const cDQ As String = """"

Public Function Loginwrong()

'Set the sql equality

Dim strsql As String

strsql = "INSERT INTO" & "[User activity tracker](Date, User, Soucetable, Researchhistory, Comments)" & _
"VALUES (Now()," & cDQ & frm.RecordSource.login & cDQ & "," & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", Attempt login)"

DoCmd.RunSQL strsql

End Function
```

Facing it, I tried another method:

```
Public Function Loginyes()

'Set the sql equality

Dim strsql As String

strsql = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "[User Activity Tracker] (Date, User, SourceTable, " _
           & " ResearchHistory, Comments) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & Environ("login") & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & "," _
           & cDQ & "Login success" & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strsql
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
```

Do you have any insights? Comments? Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this is an English-Language site and all questions and answers should therefore be in English.

Comment: Ok Sorry, I will modify it to fit the rules then :)

Comment: Nevermind, I did find the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I finally did find a solution for this function.

Just pasting it in case other people needs it:

```
Public Function Loginwrong()

'Define the elements dimensions
Dim frm As Form
Dim strsql As String

'Set the equality to have the current form used taken into account
Set frm = Screen.ActiveForm


'Use it to find values of the given controls
strsql = "INSERT INTO [User Activity]([Date], [User], SourceTable, Comments)" _
& "" & "VALUES(Now()," & "'" & frm.[login].Value & "','" & frm.Name & "', 'Wrong Password'" & "'" & frm.[passwordlogin].Value & "');"


        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strsql
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Function
```

What I forgot in the first coding was adding the '' so It could be considered as text answers.*